# Suggestions for brushing the insides of lower back teeth

Tags: phonetics, vowels

When I brush my toddler's teeth, I want good access to the [lingual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_terminology) (inside) side of the lower back teeth, to brush them. Thus, I want my kid with parted lips and teeth and with the tongue pulled away from the lower back teeth. When I say "say [a]"<sup>[1]</sup>, that parts the lips and teeth, but the tongue oftentimes remains resting against the lower back teeth. What can I say ("say […]") to get the desired mouth position?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I think that's the transcription, anyway. The sound I say is the (central?) one I use in *dot-com* and *pot* and *flop* and *Tom* (not the back [ɑ] in *calm* or *far* or *con* or *father*). Cf. http://tinyurl.com/qqm8.

Comment: IMO, linguistics is mostly irrelevant for this. Try http://parenting.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't use a vowel, use a consonant. Say "ock", and freeze the /k/ position at the end. That will keep the tongue apex away from the teeth altogether, because the back of the tongue is touching the soft palate right above the uvula. And phonetics (a part of linguistics) is always useful in describing tongue positions.

Comment: I think this is a very good question, and a linguistically relevant one as well.

Comment: @jlawler: some kinds of kissing involve sequences of tongue positions, and it's conceivable that there's an IPA sequence, which if practised, would produce a desirable effect. I'd find that question just as off-topic :). I did my best to avoid cunning linguist jokes.

Comment: @prash: And you almost made it. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's offtopic.

Comment: @jlawler, perhaps /x/, then?

Comment: [x] is in the same position as [k] except it lets air through under pressure. If position is all you're interested in, any velar consonant will work; so will uvulars if you want the tongue root further back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the proper technique for brushing a toddler's teeth has nothing to do with linguistics.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann ?? I didn't ask for the proper technique for brushing. I asked for what sound to make when I wish a particular position of the tongue.

Comment: Yes, but what you want to know concerns a tongue position that will facilitate access to the teeth for the purposes of brushing.  So my close-vote stands.

Comment: @jlawler, just so you know, I tried different things and /x/ wound up working well. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your toddler is producing a front [a]. You might try getting a back [ɑ] with "say *aw*" (the sound in *father* or *law*, in most US dialects anyway).

Comment: Thanks much. I've edited the question to (I hope) clarify it. I'd appreciate if you see whether you wish to emend your answer in light of that edit.